# Cannot connect to mongoLab while testing web app using iPhone

Tags: jquery, mongodb, jquery-mobile, mlab

I am creating a simple application to get form inputs and send them to MongoLab database. I am new to MongoDB and MongoLab. However, it is working well when I use my laptops's browser to test the application. But, when I try to test it with my mobile device (iPhone 6) it doesn't works. This is my code I am using to connect to mongoLab. See if anyone can help me.

```
    $.ajax({
         url: "mongodb://user:1234@ds025802.mlab.com:25802/datalogger",

                  data: JSON.stringify({
                      "Header": header,
                      "data" : data

                      }),
                  type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json",

          success: function(data){
                console.log("data inserted");
              window.location.href="index.html";

              },error: function(xhr, status, err){

                  console.log(err);

                  }
```